Loading historical satellite images from Google into QGIS
In Google Earth, you can show historical satellite images from different time periods, where available as can be seen on the screenshot below.
How can I load these historical images as background layer into QGIS? Using this script by Klas Karlsson, I can add several background maps as XYZ tiles, including Google Satellite. However, this seems to be the current image only.
This is what I would like to achieve in QGIS: loadin a (historical) background image, here one from 12/2002:


That should be available via GEE.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNbzhlMHekU
